# Lower periodic subsets of groups and semigroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, groupoids

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a group or semigroup. We call $A$ left
 upper [resp. lower] $B$-periodic if $BA\subseteq A$
[resp. $A\subseteq BA$]. If $A$ is both left  upper and
lower $B$-periodic (i.e. $BA=A$ ), then we call it left
 $B$-periodic. It is a generalization of the conceptions ideals, sub-semigroups and subgroups (for more information, one can see http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1005386711000332?journalCode=ac) .

Now, we are looking for some (finite, infinite) groups/semigroups containing a  non-singleton
subset $B\neq \emptyset$ such that for every subset $A$ the following property holds
$$
A\subseteq BA\Rightarrow A\subseteq bA\; \mbox{; for all } b\in B
$$

(Note that in groups it is equivalent to "$A\subseteq BA\Rightarrow B^{-1}A\subseteq A$".
Also, if $B^{-1}\subseteq B$ then $A=BA$ implies $A=bA$, for all $b\in B$)

Comment: Let B be a right zero, so that ab=z for all a in S and b in B.  Then S and B yield your property.

Comment: You may also need z (and B) to be a left zero to guarantee associativity. and I think I reversed left and right above: try ba=z instead.

Comment: If $B$ is a subset of left zeros with more than two elements, then it does not have the property. If $B$ is a subset of left identities, then it has the property. But,  I'm looking for some other (non-trivial) subsets with the property (specially in groups).

Comment: As I understand your property, (and if I get the direction right), the only time the condition A contained in BA holds is if A is contained in singleton z, in which case the consequent is obvious. So the condition does hold, but may be less interesting. Another case is when B consizts of a single elements and acts like a cyclic derangement.